# Normalization to 3NF Homework Help

Tags: database-design, normalization

How would I normalize the following data to 3NF. Can someone tell me or set up an example of at least the 1NF and show the steps? Any FKs and PKs need to be used accordingly. A picture of the normal form structure an ERD or screenshots would be helpful.

PersonID
Person Name
Person Address
Person Phone Numbers
Person SSN
Marital Status
Person DOB
Spouse Name
Spouse Address
Spouse Phone Numbers
Spouse SSN
Spouse DOB
Marital Status
Child1 Name
Child1 Address
Child1 Phone Numbers
Child1 SSN
Child1 DOB
Marital Status
Child2 Name
Child2 Address
Child2 Phone Numbers
Child2 SSN
Child2 DOB
Marital Status
Child3 Name
Child3 Address
Child3 Phone Numbers
Child3 SSN
Child3 DOB
Marital Status
Vehicle Make
Vehicle Model
Vehicle Year
Vehicle Color
Vehicle Mileage
Vehicle Body Type
Vehicle Repair Date
Vehicle Repair Description
Vehicle Repair Cost
Vehicle Repair Shop Name
Vehicle Repair Shop Address
Repair Shop Phone Numbers
Repair Shop Owner Name
Repair Shop Owner Address
Repair Shop Owner Phone Numbers

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We're not opposed to helping out with homework but have a go and show us what you have and where you are stuck

Comment: Try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) for starters! Hint: Take the letters S, C, V and R and make new tables out them! Link them with a person_id field - get back to us when you've done at least that! Which text did your lecturer recommend? Try reading some of it!  I usually find that reading about a topic can help when studying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider learning and understanding 1nf, 2nf and 3nf link 
http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

and you can consider learning & understanding how constructing erd diagrams 
https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/er-diagrams
http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/er-diagrams-tutorial/